# Problem debugging kivy app in ubntu linux, when i tried to debug the app it started import requirements and then showd the error and exited

Tags: python, android, ubuntu, kivy, kivy-language

```
>     [INFO]:    Build freetype (without harfbuzz)
>     [INFO]:    Configure args are:
>             ---without-bzip2
>             ---prefix=/home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/freetype/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/freetype
>             ---host=arm-linux-androideabi
>             ---with-png=no
>             ---with-harfbuzz=no
>             ---with-zlib=yes
>             ---disable-static
>             ---enable-shared
>     [INFO]:    -> directory context /home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/freetype/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/freetype
>     [INFO]:    -> running configure --without-bzip2 --prefix=/home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arme...(and
> 182 more)
>                working: make: *** [builds/unix/detect.mk:91: setup] Error 77                                                              
> Exception in thread background thread for pid 20575:
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
>         self.run()
>       File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
>         self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.8.egg/sh.py",
> line 1683, in wrap
>         fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.8.egg/sh.py",
> line 2662, in background_thread
>         handle_exit_code(exit_code)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.8.egg/sh.py",
> line 2349, in fn
>         return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.8.egg/sh.py",
> line 905, in handle_command_exit_code
>         raise exc
>     sh.ErrorReturnCode_2:
>     
>       RAN: /home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/freetype/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/freetype/configure
> --without-bzip2 --prefix=/home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/freetype/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/freetype
> --host=arm-linux-androideabi --with-png=no --with-harfbuzz=no --with-zlib=yes --disable-static --enable-shared
>     
>       STDOUT:
>     
>     FreeType build system -- automatic system detection
>     
>     The following settings are used:
>     
>       platform                    unix
>       compiler                    /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
> -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC
>       configuration directory     ./builds/unix
>       configuration rules         ./builds/unix/unix.mk
>     
>     If this does not correspond to your system or settings please remove the file
>     `config.mk' from this directory then read the INSTALL file for help.
>     
>     Otherwise, simply type `make -j4' again to build the library,
>     or `make -j4 refdoc' to build the API reference (this needs python >= 2.6).
>     
>     cd builds/unix; \
>             ./configure  '--without-bzip2' '--prefix=/home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/freetype/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/freetype'
> '--host=arm-linux-androideabi' '--with-png=no' '--with-harfbuzz=no'
> '--with-zlib=yes' '--disable-static' '--enable-shared'
>     checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
>     checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
>     checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
> -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC
>     checking whether the C compiler works... no
>     configure: error: in `/home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/freetype/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/freetype/builds/unix':
>     configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
>     See `config.log' for more details
>     make: *** [builds/unix/detect.mk:91: setup] Error 77
>     
>     
>       STDERR:
>     
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
>         return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
>       File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
>         exec(code, run_globals)
>       File "/home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py",
> line 1260, in <module>
>         main()
>       File "/home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py",
> line 18, in main
>         ToolchainCL()
>       File "/home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py",
> line 709, in __init__
>         getattr(self, command)(args)
>       File "/home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py",
> line 154, in wrapper_func
>         build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
>       File "/home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py",
> line 213, in build_dist_from_args
>         build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
>       File "/home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py",
> line 577, in build_recipes
>         recipe.build_arch(arch)
>       File "/home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/freetype/__init__.py",
> line 114, in build_arch
>         shprint(configure, *config_args, _env=env)
>       File "/home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py",
> line 167, in shprint
>         for line in output:
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.8.egg/sh.py",
> line 953, in next
>         self.wait()
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.8.egg/sh.py",
> line 879, in wait
>         self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.8.egg/sh.py",
> line 905, in handle_command_exit_code
>         raise exc
>     sh.ErrorReturnCode_2:
>     
>       RAN: /home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/freetype/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/freetype/configure
> --without-bzip2 --prefix=/home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/freetype/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/freetype
> --host=arm-linux-androideabi --with-png=no --with-harfbuzz=no --with-zlib=yes --disable-static --enable-shared
>     
>       STDOUT:
>     
>     FreeType build system -- automatic system detection
>     
>     The following settings are used:
>     
>       platform                    unix
>       compiler                    /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
> -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC
>       configuration directory     ./builds/unix
>       configuration rules         ./builds/unix/unix.mk
>     
>     If this does not correspond to your system or settings please remove the file
>     `config.mk' from this directory then read the INSTALL file for help.
>     
>     Otherwise, simply type `make -j4' again to build the library,
>     or `make -j4 refdoc' to build the API reference (this needs python >= 2.6).
>     
>     cd builds/unix; \
>             ./configure  '--without-bzip2' '--prefix=/home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/freetype/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/freetype'
> '--host=arm-linux-androideabi' '--with-png=no' '--with-harfbuzz=no'
> '--with-zlib=yes' '--disable-static' '--enable-shared'
>     checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
>     checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
>     checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
> -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC
>     checking whether the C compiler works... no
>     configure: error: in `/home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/freetype/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/freetype/builds/unix':
>     configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
>     See `config.log' for more details
>     make: *** [builds/unix/detect.mk:91: setup] Error 77
>     
>     
>       STDERR:
>     
>     # Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=Scientifi Researcher --bootstrap=sdl2
> --requirements=python3,kivy,kivymd,youtubesearchpython,selenium,os,time,PIL,requests,hashlib,io,googlesearch,bs4,lxml,json,pytube,PyPDF2,pdf2docx,gTTS,random,docx,ssl,urllib
> --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/bhyry/sciresearcher/CompetitionProject/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a"
> --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py
>     # ENVIRONMENT:
>     #     LANG = 'C.UTF-8'
>     #     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
>     #     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
>     #     DISPLAY = ':0'
>     #     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin'
>     #     MAIL = '/var/mail/root'
>     #     LOGNAME = 'root'
>     #     USER = 'root'
>     #     HOME = '/root'
>     #     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
>     #     SUDO_COMMAND = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer -v android debug'
>     #     SUDO_USER = 'bhyry'
>     #     SUDO_UID = '1000'
>     #     SUDO_GID = '1000'
>     #     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
>     #     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
>     #     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
>     #     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
>     #     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
>     #
>     # Buildozer failed to execute the last command
>     # The error might be hidden in the log above this error
>     # Please read the full log, and search for it before
>     # raising an issue with buildozer itself.
>     # In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

This is The terminal codes with error. I run sudo buildozer -v android debug, it imported some modules and then stopped and showed the error. I installed freetype2 and it still showing the error.

Before the error the terminal showed the following:

> Are you sure you want to continue [y/n]? y
>
> [INFO]:    Recipe build order is ['freetype', 'hostpython3', 'jpeg', 'libffi', 'librt', 'libxml2', 'openssl', 'png', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sqlite3', 'libxslt', 'python3', 'sdl2', 'setuptools', 'lxml', 'pil', 'six', 'pyjnius', 'android', 'kivy']
>
> [INFO]:    The requirements (bs4, certifi, docx, googlesearch, gtts, hashlib, io, json, kivymd, os, pdf2docx, pypdf2, pytube, random, requests, selenium, ssl, time, urllib, youtubesearchpython) were not found as recipes, they will be installed with pip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,youtubesearchpython,selenium,os,time,PIL,requests,hashlib,io,googlesearch,bs4,lxml,json,pytube,PyPDF2,pdf2docx,gTTS,random,docx,ssl,urllib
```

You must add to requirments only third party modules.

Modules like

```
os, random, time
```

are not third party module and that's why you get the error.

and try also install in colab this packages :

```
sudo apt-get install automake autoconf libtool libltdl-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like some of your requirements names are not matching or it could not find it , here is a link on how to make sure you have those requirements recipes build for kivy.

https://github.com/Android-for-Python/Android-for-Python-Users#requirements

This would give you a good idea of how the build works..

Comment: I tried and did that and it still showing the error, when i removed the requirements to default, it works, but, when i run app on my mobile it tries oppening the app and then suddenly closes,  i am using android9 i will share the whole app with files, so you can check please                                    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kH339KgW18s9Ib1hN3to4LOUBuu-AZMd/view?usp=sharing